# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_ajax' (is_ajax has been defined in the views.py file)

Tags: python, django

I have included the following is_ajax() function, so that I can use it in another Django view function in the same views.py file:

```
def is_ajax(request):
return request.META.get(‘HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH’) == ‘XMLHttpRequest’
```

However, the problem is that I am still getting the following error message in the terminal:
AttributeError: ‘WSGIRequest’ object has no attribute ‘is_ajax’

The following image shows the views.py file where the is_ajax() function is being called on line 48:
[is_ajax() function in the views.py file line 48](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqmLh.png)

I will appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Try "if is_ajax(request):" in the views.py

Comment: Hi. The problem is that when I attempt this, I get the following error instead: ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7fe265fff400>>": "ExamResult.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: This is a error not related to the change and the question. Somewhere elese in your code path you assign something like `request.user` to exam_result.user`

Answer (score 1):

```py
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get(‘HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH’) == ‘XMLHttpRequest’

def save_exam_view(request, pk):
    if is_ajax(request):
        # do something if it is a AJAX request
```